# Linq Query: Sum of columns for a given row

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I searched a lot of questions posted here but I'm unable to find a better solution for my problem.

I have a table with 6 columns storing decimal values and want to do a sum of all the columns in the query. Currently this is what I am doing.

```
(from i in db.OperationalValues
 where i.Timestamp == date
 select new
 {
   CumulativeValues = i.Value1.GetValueOrDefault(0)
                           + i.Value2.GetValueOrDefault(0)
                           + i.Value3.GetValueOrDefault(0)
                           + i.Value4.GetValueOrDefault(0)
                           + i.Value5.GetValueOrDefault(0)
                           + i.Value6.GetValueOrDefault(0),
 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have looked at many questions and answers but was hoping to get a better way to write this LINQ query. As the table could have more columns and if the number of columns increase the query will become huge.

If anyone has a better way to write this LINQ query, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = new { CumulativeValues = 0 };
var item = db.OperationalValues.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Timestamp == date);
if (item != null)
    result = new { CumulativeValues = item.Value1 ?? 0 + item.Value2 ?? 0 + item.Value3 ?? 0 + item.Value4 ?? 0 + item.Value5 ?? 0 + item.Value6 ?? 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the best/only way to go without delving into reflection for finding the decimal property types.

However, if you have loads of these "value" columns then you might want to redesign your database to move them into rows in a related table. If you did that then you could make use of the `Sum` functionality of Linq-to-sql.

Comment: i wish i could redesign the database, but not under my scope. :(

Answer (score 0):

It think this is an option you have because of the dynamic nature you mention:

[Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: i have looked at this website many time but still unable to figure out on how it can simplify my query. If you have sm sample just show me that would be of great help.